Define a generic function in a custom environment
I spent the last 2 days trying to define a generic function in my own environment, but somehow I do not manage to get there.
First off, some code to demonstrate my issue:
# my custom environment
my_env <- new.env()

# my generic function foo
my_env$foo <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod('foo', x)
}

my_env$foo.character <- function(x, ...) {
   print(paste('I am a character!', x))
}

my_env$foo('Hello!')

This gives me the following error message: Error in UseMethod("foo", x): no applicable method for 'foo' applied to an object of class "character"
What I learned so far from the docs of UseMethod:

To support this, UseMethod and NextMethod search for methods in two places: in the environment in which the generic function is called, and in the registration data base for the environment in which the generic is defined (typically a namespace)
So as far as I understand, it searches in the global environment (where it is called) and in my_env, because thats where the definition of it is. But if that would be the case, I would not get the error message.

So I also tried attaching the function to the environment, after defining the generic:
# my custom environment
my_env <- new.env()

# my generic function foo
foo <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod('foo', x)
}

foo.character <- function(x, ...) {
   print(paste('I am a character!', x))
}

my_env$foo <- foo

my_env$foo('Hello!')

I also tried UseMethod with the environment reference:
# my custom environment
my_env <- new.env()

# my generic function foo
my_env$foo <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod('my_env$foo', x)
}

my_env$foo.character <- function(x, ...) {
   print(paste('I am a character!', x))
}

my_env$foo('Hello!')

I also attached the my_env:
# my custom environment
my_env <- new.env()

# my generic function foo
my_env$foo <- function(x, ...) {
   UseMethod('foo', x)
}

my_env$foo.character <- function(x, ...) {
   print(paste('I am a character!', x))
}

attach(my_env)

my_env$foo('Hello!')

But none of these changed anything for me. I didn't really find anything about this topic on the internet and I can't believe that I'm the only one trying to use environments and generics together, since it does not make any sense to use environments at all, if it can only hold "dumb" lists and variables, but no functions and it seems to work perfectly in the context of packages.
Can anyone explain to me, what I do wrong? I appreciate any constructive comments :)

Option 1: Call the generic within the environment.
with(my_env, foo('Hello!'))
#[1] "I am a character! Hello!"

Option 2: Register the method, so that it is "in the registration data base".
with(my_env,.S3method("foo", "character", "foo.character"))

my_env$foo('Hello!')
#[1] "I am a character! Hello!"


registerS3method can be used here.  It has an envir= argument.

Sure but its  documentation says it is "[n]ot intended to be called directly". Whereas help(".S3method") says "This function should only be used in R scripts".

I imagine if there's also a foo that is not in that environment, and a foo.character designed to work with that other generic, things would not work out well.

@user2554330 You can test that. I would consider such a setup fragile and just asking for a bug.

Thank you! This solved my problem! But I noticed, that function .S3method() the second option has different parameters:
with(my_env, .S3method("foo", "character", sep = "."))

@SaskiaSchild Are you using an old R version? Because at least in the current version that is incorrect.

Ah sorry, I totally forgot. Yes, I'm bound to R version 4.0.4 at the moment.

Something like:
# my custom environment
my_env <- new.env()

# my generic function foo
my_env$foo <- function(x, ...) {
  UseMethod('foo', x)
}

foo.character <- function(x, ...) {
  print(paste('I am a character!', x))
}

my_env$foo("ala")
#> [1] "I am a character! ala"

Created on 2024-10-30 with reprex v2.1.0

Thank you for the input! One question: foo.character in this example is defined in the global environment - am I right? So what's the point of using an environment, if I can't define the generic implementations inside the environment?

You have to define the method first withing environment.
